# multi region apache cassandra in autoscaling group in AWS

Tags: cassandra, autoscaling, launch-configuration

For a multi-region setup of Apache Cassandra in autoscaling group, where the two regions are peered to communicate on a private network, meaning no public IPs. All private IPs for communications between nodes in the multiple regions.

What is the recommended snitch to use in this situation in production?
I do know of the default EC2MultiRegionSnitch but that takes into account I have public IPs to communicate across regions, but my case is different as I have all private IPs only.

I am also thinking RackInferingSnitch and GossipingPropertyFileSnitch but will like to get some expert recommendations and challenges from people currently running multi-region Cassandra in production.

Also, how are you able to manage configuration changes with the autoscaling group in AWS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. But I think you should re-think using auto-scaling groups. Consider how the data would be re-balanced when the cluster is growing or shrinking. All of the primary partition ranges would be changed and that data would need to be streamed to the new responsible node. Tons of compactions as well. This data movement will have a significant impact on performance.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172335/aws-and-auto-scaling-cassandra/%22this%20discussion%22) for a similar discussion.

Comment: that was what i thought too because there is so much buzz around autoscaling and stateless architecture that i wanted to see the visibility of having cassandra in an autoscaling group. I mean i always believe databases should be left out of the stateless mantra to be honest